# Multiple copper pours in ground plane of a 2 layer board

Tags: pcb, ground-plane, copper-pour

I am an amateur PCB designer.Trying to design my first PCB. I am using a two-layered power supply board. I am using a 72V battery pack as the input to get +15V,+5V, and -15V as outputs. The pic shows that my bottom layer has 4 copper pours (GND, AGND, 72V(for enable pin), and 5V). Having Brocken ground plane cause EMI issues

[image]

Comment: a trace is enough for an enable pin. separate Grounds are generally not recommended unless under very special circumstances. Judging from density, youd be better off with a solid GND bottom layer and everything else on top, apart from where you need short bridges.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Got rid of 72V and 5V pours. But I can't get rid of AGND. Will it be ok to have an Analog ground Island in the bottom layer?

Comment: for what do you need AGND ?

Comment: The IC I am using needs an AGND. They are GND and AGND are internally connected and has been specifically pointed out in the datasheet to not connect them externally

Comment: In this case, I am 99% sure that the advice in the datasheet is misleading for most projects and separate AGND is neither necessary nor beneficial

Comment: Without writing an entire chapter, split ground planes are generally beneficial only when the current between the two planes can be isolated. In that case, you connect the two planes together with a single trace, and on the other side of the board, exactly above that trace, you place another trace with exactly the same current going in the opposite direction. If you are not able to accomplish that, then you're better of with a single, large ground plane.

Answer (score 1):

When designing a 2 Layer PCB, it is always a good practice to make the bottom layer a solid ground. There should be no splits, traces running on this layer. This layer purely acts as a reference plane for the signal lines and power planes present on the top plane/layer. You can split the top layer into various planes like, VDD, Analog ground, in your case +15V,+5V, and -15V and ideally route all of your signals on this layer.

When it comes to the enable pin, it is just a logic high or logic low pin. You don't have to create a plane, just a trace is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases a separate AGND is not necessary and usually creates common mode problems because the resistance between the grounds will create voltage differences with any current running through it.

Also, if you are running large currents through the board, you will need to worry about the return currents through the ground plane. But it really depends on the resolution of the ADC's needed and their range.

Comment: I don't have any ADC's in my schematic. The IC in question is LT3958 which is a DC/DC converter. The datasheet says AGND and GND are connected internally and should not be connected again externally.

Comment: @gautam023 what schematic?